# arel union giving unexpected sql query in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

So I'm trying to combine 2 ActiveRecord::relation results into 1 (basically an OR type operation).  since Rails 4 has no intention of having this as a feature, I've turned to Arel.  You can see from the below code it is not combining both relations to a proper sql query.  How do I do it so that I end up with an SQL query such that I have "kites.flying_status=Flying" instead of "kites.flying_status=UNION SELECT..." in the combined statement?

```
@kites = Kite.search_kites("red").by_flying_status("Flying)")
```

**SQL result of kites.to_sql**

```
"SELECT \"kites\".* FROM \"kites\" WHERE \"kites\".\"id\" IN (336, 334, 176, 238, 335, 162, 439, 385, 158, 276, 379, 378, 310, 391, 416, 342, 281) AND \"kites\".\"flying_status\" = 'Flying'"
```

**SQL result of Kite.where(id: locs.pluck(:kite_id)).to_sql**

```
 "SELECT \"kites\".* FROM \"kites\" WHERE \"kites\".\"id\" IN (162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238)"
```

The code for combining both activerecord relations:

```
arel_union_trials = @kites.union(Kite.where(id: locs.pluck(:kite_id)))
kite_arel_table = Kite.arel_table
@kites = Kite.from(kite_arel_table.create_table_alias(arel_union_trials, :kites)).distinct
```

**@kites.union(Kite.where(id: locs.pluck(:kite_id))).to_sql result:**

```
SELECT "kites".* FROM ( SELECT "kites".* FROM "kites" WHERE "kites"."id" IN (336, 334, 176, 238, 335, 162, 439, 385, 158, 276, 379, 378, 310, 391, 416, 342, 281) AND "kites"."flying_status" =  UNION SELECT "kites".* FROM "kites" WHERE "kites"."id" IN (162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238) ) "kites"
E, [2015-02-27T12:48:12.941237 #7408] ERROR -- : PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
LINE 1: ...281) AND "kites"."flying_status" =  UNION SELE...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "kites".* FROM ( SELECT "kites".* FROM "kites" WHERE "kites"."id" IN (336, 334, 176, 238, 335, 162, 439, 385, 158, 276, 379, 378, 310, 391, 416, 342, 281) AND "kites"."flying_status" =  UNION SELECT "kites".* FROM "kites" WHERE "kites"."id" IN (162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 162, 162, 238, 238, 238) ) "kites"
```

Comment: Why people think patterns like this are easier than SQL is beyond me. Any way of just writing the plain SQL, I could debug it in like a quadrillasecond (or something Napoleon Dynamite would say)

Comment: can you post the code for both the search_kites and by_flying_status methods?